# How can I detect all images loaded inside an HTML binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

In my components template i have a container like this

```
<div [innerHTML]="somehtml | safeHtml"></div>
```

The HTML contains images with standard image tags 
like

`<img src="http://google.com/someimage.png"/>`

I want to know when the images inside my HTML are fully loaded. How can i check for this?

P.S.: safehtml is just a sanitizer-pipe

EDIT: I am looking for an event based solution rather than check in time-intervals! Also i need a solution specificly for this container

Comment: you could do something like: 
`jQuery(window).load(function () {
    alert('page is loaded');

    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('page is loaded and 1 minute has passed');   
    }, 60000);

});`

Comment: @DigitalJedi no, this would only trigger if everything on the page is loaded

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this. I don't love it since it's not the angular way, but since your template is a string, I hardly believe there's something better:

HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="somehtml | safeHtml" id="div-to-check"></div>
```

TS:

```
this.somehtml = `your html`;
window.setTimeout(() => { // Let's make it async to execute it in the next tick
  const promises = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#div-to-check img')
  ) // get all images
  .map((img: HTMLImageElement) => {
    if (img.complete) {
      return Promise.resolve(); // Check if the image already loaded. Maybe it's been too fast
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      img.onload = resolve; // it resolves when it loads
      img.onerror = reject; // avoids infinite waiting
    });
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('all images loaded!');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.error('an image didn\'t load');
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah this is the direction i am looking for because it does not rely on time-intervals and works for the specific container. As you said though, not the angular way.

Comment: Also passing the template as a string it's not the angular way :P the angular way is having an array of `img` objects and check the `onload` callback to each of them **before** inserting in the dom. But in this case, your elements start existing only when you do [innerHTML], so this is the only solution

Comment: Well this is a CMS-Like use case, i have HTML that is provided by some User. if i want to do it like you say i would have to parse the Users HTML first.

Comment: And, I add, Angular won't know that the those elements exist. You should create a [dynamic component](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) for each `img` and then query them with `ViewChild` maybe. This sounds like overkilling

Comment: the fact is that you can't parse HTML until you don't append it to some DOM. You can create a fake document and then append the HTML, insert the `onload` callbacks and then remove the elements from the fake document and append to the real DOM, but it doesn't change much from this implementation. Maybe it would avoid the async step

Comment: Well i would be able to parse it in backend, that's what i meant. but that doesn't really seem clean to me at all

Comment: Oooh if you want to parse it in the backend is another pair of shoes. You can use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

Comment: I'd prefer a frontend-only solution. Yours seems to be the best so far

Answer (score 0):

Next time please read some other questions first, and try to solve your problem yourself, before writing your own question
But here's the solution:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
        alert('page is loaded');

        setTimeout(function () {
            alert('page is loaded and 1 minute has passed');   
        }, 60000);

    });
```

Comment: yeah sure, but this is just interval-based checking. I want to listen for an event or subscribe to something

Comment: sorry, you are right. Anyway this really would mean that everything else on the page is loaded too, not only my images inside the div. Correct?

Comment: then it is not what your solution and the other solutions you probably were referring to provide. My use case is: i have several containers with bound HTML that is provided by users via CMS and i want to make a loading-animation for each container until it is fully initialized. However the animation should be gone when the specific container's content is ready.